# MVC 3 split parameters in HttpPost action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-post, model-binding

I have an MVC 3 app and I have created a generic wrapper object, which has some navigation properties and the wrapped object of T, whose values I'm editing/displaying.

```
public class NavigationViewModel<T>
{
    public T Model { get; set; }
    public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper { get; set; }

    public NavigationViewModel() { }

    public NavigationViewModel(T model, NavigationHelper helper)
    {
        this.Model = model;
        this.NavigationHelper = helper;
    }
}
```

My controller resolves this object nicely in an action like this:

```
public ActionResult Foo(NavigationViewModel<Bar> viewModel)
```

Code in my view looks like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model.SomeProperty)
```

My colleague said that that code is not nice to read. I already have a strongly typed view, the Model and this Model has another property called Model. He suggested to rename the Model property to ViewModel and I agreed with his reasoning.

Now, the code with the renamed properties does not work anymore: NavigationViewModel viewModel is null. So I changed the signature of the HttpPost method to the following and it works again:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(NavigationHelper helper, Bar viewModel)
```

I like this very much! I can directly access my viewModel in code, the code in the view makes sense and the helper object does not get in the way. I haven't seen this convention before and I guess it worked before because of the naming convention. Using a property called Model hinted at how to resolve the object. Without that property, it couldn't resolve it anymore.

I would like to adopt this for other kinds of helpers that contain view-specific properties, like select-lists or other properties that I otherwise might have put in my ViewBag. Would you guys recommend this approach or will I run into trouble later on using this?

Comment: Generics are good, but quite often they lead to over-engineering. What are you trying to achieve? Regarding the naming conventions, I think that your colleague is right, but just calling it a view model solves half a problem. I'd expect to be able to identify the purpose of the class just by looking at its name and properties.

Comment: The navigation viewmodel is a vehicle to tag along all kinds of information, like which button was pressed to cause the postback and if I want to show buttons (we are designing a very dynamic and weird flow). I can reuse this part and let the T, the viewmodel, be interchangable. Calling it a viewmodel might not be any clearer, but it made me discover that you can use/abuse/trick the model binder into resolving two objects instead of a wrapper with an inner object.

Comment: This sounds like design issue. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you are saying that you want to track a state of the page that user is working with. If that's the case, then web forms might be a better solution to this. Also, hearing "post-backs" with MVC sounds wrong. Maybe try sharing more information about your design? Either way, this is quite interesting and it'd be good to see more opinions.

Comment: I have a next, previous and overview button and based on the state of the overall object (somewhere on the server, let's call that a Foo), I decide whether or not someone should see any of those buttons. The problem is, there are all kinds of Foos and they share the same properties, but not the same behaviour. FooA does have a previous button, but FooB does not, given the same state of their properties. And postback might be a remnant of webforms, I should have said 'post the form'. And yes, the interaction design has been quite 'challenging' to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a really simple answer for you, just don't name your action parameter viewModel, so change:

```
public ActionResult Foo(NavigationViewModel viewModel)
```

```
public ActionResult Foo(NavigationViewModel model)
```

Or any other parameter name that does not collide with your ViewModel property on your NavigationViewModel class.